# How do I resolve my error  when trying to convert a data type of VarChar to a Numeric type?

Tags: c#, .net

On the line `date=(int) datamanager.ExecuteScalar(CommandType.Text, Query);` I am getting an error saying:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

In the `GETEDITDATE` query I'm trying to retrieve data that is of type `varchar`. How do I resolve this issue?

**Code:**

```
public string returneditdate(string receiptid, string ConString) {
    string Query = string.Empty;
    int date = 0;
    string dat = string.Empty;
    DataManager datamanager = null;
    try {
        datamanager = Supporter.GetDataManager();
        datamanager.ConnectionString = ConString;
        datamanager.Open();
        Query = DataSourceSQLConstants.GETEDITDATE.Replace("@fldreceiptid", receiptid.ToString());
        date = (int) datamanager.ExecuteScalar(CommandType.Text, Query);
        dat = date.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The relevant info to post here is the text of GETEDITDATE (before and after Replace).

Comment: GETEDITDATE = "select fldreciptdate from tblrecipt where fldreciptid='@fldreciptid'"; fldreceiptid is in numeric datatype and fldreceiptdate is in varchar datatype        after replace the text will be select fldreciptdate from tblrecipt where fldreciptid=1;

Comment: So something called 'date' is a VarChar in the Db and you want it as `int` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a varchar datatype, it is text. You need to use `int.Parse` method to convert it to a integer.